# Razor code comments

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to re-write very long complex if statements and switch statements inside my razor view .   So comments would definetly help the readibility.  Problem is this

```
@if(IsManager(){
    switch(Model.ReportType){
       case ReportType.NewReport:
           if (case1){
               // bla bla bla
               //
            }
            else if (case2){
               // bla blab bla
               //
            }
            break;
       case ReportType.FooReport:
            if (fooBar){
               ....
```

so any ways, there is very simplified example of something that would be in a razor code block. Now if I want to add simple comments in there to help readibility - it all breaks!! ex.

```
@if(IsManager(){                          @*  TALENT MANAGER   *@
        switch(Model.ReportType){
           case ReportType.NewReport:
```

that makes intellisense get really mad for some reason, I tried this style of comment

```
@if(IsManager(){                          //  TALENT MANAGER   
        switch(Model.ReportType){
           case ReportType.NewReport:
```

no luck , am I doing something wrong??

Comment: One would argue that if you have complex logic in your Razor view you are doing it wrong.

Comment: The complex logic belongs in the Controller, Model or another abstraction?  Return a model that is what the view needs.

Comment: This looks like code that would belong in the model (or an intermediary view model), not in the view.  The view should be nothing more (or little more) than just binding to values on the model.

Comment: @Belogix - I probably worded that wrong , There is no complex logic , there are just many different types of users and roles possible , and there are a lot of diferent inputs available for different roles, but it is not actually doing anything - if that makes sense

Comment: @ScottSelby Is your `if` statement borked? `@if(IsManager(){` should be `@if(IsManager()) {`

Comment: @RGraham - just pseudo code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group reusable (or complex) view code into a [helper](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/working-with-pages/creating-and-using-a-helper-in-an-aspnet-web-pages-site). Helpers are definable in their own file or in a view.

```
@helper DoSomethingWhenManager(bool isManager, ReportModel model)
{
    if(isManager)
    {
        switch(model.ReportType) // This is a comment about the report
        {
            // ...
        }
    {
}
```

View:

```
<div>
    @DoSomethingWhenManager(IsManager(), Model)
</div>
```

Comment: I could probably make a helper work, where does the top block @helper go ?  like in a partial view?

Comment: I put them at the top of the view I am working on, but they can be inside their own file.

Answer (score 0):

This one works fine for me

```
@if (1 < 9) { //Hello
        <b>Hey, there!</b>
    }
```

I use Visual Studio 2013 Express for Web

Comment: after the } of the end of the if , continue with a else if and see if that works